# Show the second dropdown once first dropdown's value selected is equal to 'Courier'

Tags: javascript, html, css

### My problem is on how to make the second drop-down display once my first dropdown value selected is Courier

> First the user must check the checkbox to show the first drop-down and this is my code

```
  <p> <input  type="checkbox" id="contract" class="icheckbox_flat-green" onclick="myFunctionCons()"> Contract </p>
```

> Once checked, this contract via dropdown (first dropdown) will be visible

```
<select id="contractvia" style="display:none" class="form-control">
              <option value="0">Via..</option>
              <option value="1">Email</option>
              <option value="2">FB Messenger</option>
              <option value="3">Courier</option>
              <option value="4">Others..</option>
 </select>
```

> My goal is to display this second dropdown once the contractvia's selected option is Courier

```
<select id="contractCourier" style="display:none" class="form-control">
               <option value="">Courier</option>
               <option value="scanned">Scanned</option>
               <option value="net">Original</option>
               <option value="mouth">Photocopy</option>
</select>
```

> My first task to show the first dropdown once the checkbox is checked is achieved using this code, but it doesn't work for displaying the second dropdown once first dropdown's selected option is 'Courier'

```
<script>
function myFunctionCons() {
    var con = document.getElementById("contract");
    var conv = document.getElementById("contractvia");
    var conc = document.getElementById("contractCourier");
    if (con.checked == true) {
        conv.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        conv.style.display = "none";
    }
    if ($("#contractvia").val() == 3)
        conc.style.display = "block";
    else
        conc.style.display = "none";
}   
</script>
```

Comment: You need an event handler for when the value of the select is changed.

Comment: Like this? It doesn't work

<option value="3" onclick="myFunctionCou()">Courier</option>

function myFunctionCou() {                                                                                  
var conc = document.getElementById("contractCourier");                                                                                        conc.style.display = "block";
 }

Comment: You seem to be using jquery. Have a look at https://api.jquery.com/change/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this in Vanilla Javascript

```js
var con = document.getElementById("contract");
var conv = document.getElementById("contractvia");
var conc = document.getElementById("contractCourier");

//On checkbox return first select
con.addEventListener('click', myFunctionCons );


//if value of option is 3 show next select
conv.addEventListener('change', showSecondSelect );

function showSecondSelect() {
 //3 is the index of courier
 if (conv.selectedIndex == 3) {
  conc.style.display = "block";
 } else {
  conc.style.display = "none";
 }
}

function myFunctionCons() {
 if (con.checked == true) {
  conv.style.display = "block";
 } else {
  conv.style.display = "none";
 }
}
```

```css
#contractvia,
#contractCourier {
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<p><input type="checkbox" id="contract" class="icheckbox_flat-green">Contract</p>

<select id="contractvia" class="form-control">
 <option value="0">Via..</option>
 <option value="1">Email</option>
 <option value="2">FB Messenger</option>
 <option value="3">Courier</option>
 <option value="4">Others..</option>
 </select>

<select id="contractCourier" class="form-control">
 <option value="Courier">Courier</option>
 <option value="scanned">Scanned</option>
 <option value="net">Original</option>
 <option value="mouth">Photocopy</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I am very new to jquery so I have been searching for the correct syntax to make it work, and finally, it worked, thanks for the help :)

Comment: Am glad. I just started learning JS so I have stayed on vanilla JS. I feel jQuery sometimes is a gun at a knife fight